# Using pronoun after conjunction where the subject is the same?

Tags: pronouns

When you're hungry, and have something in your freezer, you eat it.

When you're hungry, and **you** have something in your freezer, you eat it.

Is it okay to not use **you** in this sentence?
If the subject is the same, is it okay not to use pronouns after the conjunction?

Comment: Not much in it, really, though personally I'd retain "you" in the second coordinate: it's perfectly natural and it doesn't represent an exact repetition of the subject in "you're" in the first coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

One can strip all the you's from that and it still only has one meaning, who is doing the eating doesn't need to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK. I just looked up an explanation and discovered that there's a name for this: conjunction reduction. See
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955

Comment: Except that nobody calls it that! It's simply a coordination of VPs: _When[ you're hungry], and [have something in your freezer]_, you eat it.